# how to assign/put a value to an index in a list in python

Tags: python

I'm creating this program in python that calculates you total cost according to how much you choose.
so the program is pizza delivery, and the user has to choose their choice of pizza out of the menu.
what I cant figure out is that how to tell python that whatever the users first,second and third choice is, the cost will be 3 dollars and the rest would be 5 dollars. 
what I mean in more dept would be that how do i tell python that the users 1st,2nd,3rd choice/input = $3.

I tried writing: menu[0:3] = 3 but that just changes the food in the array/list.
[this is a sample of my code(not the full code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qJ3h.png)

Comment: Please, post your code in proper written format, not in picture !

Comment: if number_of_pizza <=3:
        print("Total cost is {} Dollars".format(number_of_pizza*3)
    elif number_of_pizza > 3:
        print("Total cost is {} Dollars".format(9+((number_of_pizza - 3)*5))
    else
        print("Minimum order is one pizza")

Comment: Questions about python code should not be tagged with the editor/ide used to write and run the code unless the editor/ide materially affects how the code runs (which is rare).

Comment: @ Terry Jan Reedy sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code :**

```
i = 1
total_cost = 0
while(True):
    choice = input("Please Enter Your Choice:")
    if(i<4):
        price = 3
        total_cost = total_cost + price
    else:
        price = 5
        total_cost = total_cost + price
    i = i + 1
    check = input("Do you want to enter another choice? (y/n)")
    if(check=="N" or check="n" or check=="No" or check=="no"):
        break

print("Total Cost : $",total_cost)
```

**Output :**

```
Please Enter Your Choice:tea                                                                                            
Do you want to enter another choice? (y/n)y                                                                             
Please Enter Your Choice:coffe                                                                                          
Do you want to enter another choice? (y/n)y                                                                             
Please Enter Your Choice:apple                                                                                          
Do you want to enter another choice? (y/n)n                                                                             
Total Cost : $ 9
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for the help because your solution made my code more efficient and also i can easily understand the code. so once again thank for helping me solve the problem.

Comment: there is however one problem, 'i' will always will be smaller than 4 so the price will always be $3.

Comment: Most welcome ! Kindly accept my answer & give upvote.

Comment: Oh ! yes. good catchup (y) I update the code . kindly check. the value of `i` must be incremented by 1 in each iteration.

Comment: usman, it works thank you for updating it and helping me once again.

Comment: @TanishBhatt most welcome. thank you fir accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def price(choice):
    if choice <= 3:
        cost = 3
    else:
        cost = 5
     return cost

price(4)

> 5
```

Comment: ill try this and update you if it works better than the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a counter variable for tracking inputs, increment it after taking each input. And then in the price section of your code, use an if statement to set price to 3 if counter < 4, else set price to 5.

```
# Create counter variable
counter = 0

# Taking user input code here
counter = counter + 1

# Later when setting price in code
if counter < 4:
    price = 3
else:
    price = 5
```

Hope this gives you some ideas, feel free to comment and ask for more clarification if you need to!

Comment: thanks for sharing and trying to help, ill try it out and update you

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, number_of_pizza+1):
    if i < 4:
        total_cost += 3
    if i >= 4:
        total_cost += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, you would want to have the menu items separated in the list as :

```
menu = ['Cheese', 'Vege delight', 'pineapple', 'pepperoni','meat lovers', 'butter chicken', 'spicy corn delight', 'veg slingshot']
```

and not in the way in which you had shown it in your image.

Comment: yes that was a mistake and i didn't want it that way, thanks for sharing.

Comment: If my answer was of any help to you, please don't forget to upvote it! Thanks!